Getting error This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xx.yy.zz, with empty referer
I am trying to create one google api which includes service APIs like Firebase Cloud Messaging API, Maps JavaScript API, Maps SDK for Android, Maps Static API, Geocoding API, Geolocation API, Cloud Vision API, Time Zone API, Places API.
Scenario 1 - When I am setting "Set an application restriction" as "None" API is working fine in Mobile apps.
Scenario 2 (Where problem arises) - When I am setting "Set an application restriction" as "iOS apps" and entering my apps bundle id in the Bundle ID field,  API is giving error - "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address "x:a:b:c:q:e:v:f"(sample IP), with empty referer."
Any suggestions to fix this would be helpful.
